# How to support the columns of a second level of an hypaethral building with reduction in space by height?

Tags: 3d, modeling, research

[image]

In this multi-leveled [hypaethral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypaethral) building model there is a problem that the columns of the second floor aren't directly situated on the columns of the first floor.

How to support the columns of the second floor while preserving the reduction in floor vicinity apparent in this model (the third floor is smaller than the second and the second floor is smaller than the first floor)?

One way would be to just make the columns of the first floor wider, but then they may cover too much space and will not appear "gentle".

This model is from the computer game *Age of Empires 2: Definitive Edition, Return of Rome*.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I realize you are asking about this here because it's about a computer graphic, and probably because you want a realistic model, but real-world architectural design considerations/problems/building techniques are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Such harmful things as real world physics and structure strength theories should not slow down painters or game graphics artists. Vaulting might be a technical workaround for the real world strength problem, but it's not needed in graphics.

Another technical solution is to use pumice stone in the 2nd level. I have red that it was widely available at least in the district of Mt.Vesuvius. Lightweight 2nd floor can be supported by not so obtrusive horizontal bars.